# Como carregar dados em uma comboBox sempre que cadastrar novos valores

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, combobox

Como eu faço para que a cada cadastro de curso seja atualizado automaticamente o combobox das matérias sem precisar fechar e abrir a aplicação de novo? Ex: Faço um cadastro de um curso "Administração" e na combobox já carregue este curso. Segue o código para inserir os dados no comboBox

```
private void ConfigCursoUC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-EVMCT3AM;Initial Catalog=dbESCOLA;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand();
        sql.Connection = con;
        sql.CommandText = "SELECT NomeCurso FROM tbCURSO";
        SqlDataReader dr = sql.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable tb = new DataTable();
        tb.Load(dr);

        cmbCurso.DisplayMember = "NomeCurso";
        cmbCurso.DataSource = tb;

    }
```

[image: Tela de cadastro de cursos e matérias]

Comment: Bruno a resposta simples para pergunta seria utilizar Ajax para fazer requisições assíncronas para o servidor e coletar os novos cursos ou simplesmente ao adicionar um novo curso fazer um um item.add no combobox com o nome do curso quando o usuário clicar em cadastrar, mas faltaram detalhes a sua pergunta para que possamos entender plenamente seu problema, você está utilizando que tecnologia junto ao C# ? Forms, Web ... E se possível poste seu código no github ou em algum outro lugar para que possamos baixa-lo e tentar te dar uma luz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer algo deste género:

```
// colocar a ConnectionString como variável global ao Form
private string connString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-EVMCT3AM;Initial Catalog=dbESCOLA;Integrated Security=True";

// criar um método para que possa ser evocado sempre que necessário
private void CarregaCursos()
{
    string sql = "SELECT Id, NomeCurso FROM tbCURSO";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Load(dr);

            cmbCurso.DataSource = null;
            cmbCurso.DataSource = dt;
            cmbCurso.DisplayMember = "NomeCurso"
            cmbCurso.ValueMember = "Id";
        }
    }
}

private void ConfigCursoUC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // evocar o método no Load do Form
    CarregaCursos();
}

private void btnCadastrarCurso(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // código para cadastrar o curso
    // ...

    // evocar o método após cadastrar o curso
    CarregaCursos();
}
```

Neste exemplo a conexão é aberta e fechada sempre que fazemos a consulta, mas pode optar por abrir a conexão quando abre o `Form` e fechar apenas quando o fecha:

```
// colocar a ConnectionString como variável global ao Form
private string connString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-EVMCT3AM;Initial Catalog=dbESCOLA;Integrated Security=True";
// colocar a conexão como variável global ao Form
private SqlConnection conn = null;

// criar um método para que possa ser evocado sempre que necessário
private void CarregaCursos()
{
    string sql = "SELECT Id, NomeCurso FROM tbCURSO";

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Load(dr);

        cmbCurso.DataSource = null;
        cmbCurso.DataSource = dt;
        cmbCurso.DisplayMember = "NomeCurso"
        cmbCurso.ValueMember = "Id";
    }
}

private void ConfigCursoUC_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // abrir a conexão
    AbreConexao();
    // evocar o método no Load do Form
    CarregaCursos();
}

private void ConfigCursoUC_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // fechar a conexão
    FechaConexao();
}

private void btnCadastrarCurso(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // código para cadastrar o curso
    // ...

    // evocar o método após cadastrar o curso
    CarregaCursos();
}

private void AbreConexao()
{
    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao abrir a conexão: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

private void FechaConexao()
{
    try
    {
        if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao fechar a conexão: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Se a resposta lhe foi útil, não se esqueça de dar um UP! :)